# No widgets show in Android 12

Tags: app-widgets

I just noticed that no widgets display on my phone. I updated to Android 12 a few weeks ago, but honestly, I don't make use of widgets, so I don't know if they worked before the upgrade.

Troubleshooting after I was not successful in resolving the issue, I saw that I can select a widget and place it on the screen, but it still doesn't display.

What setting can I check that could cause this problem besides the 'normal' ones, like allowing the widget to overlay programs?

Comment: Could you mention the device model? Have you tried different home screen/launcher apps? Is the device by chance using Android Go?

Comment: The phone is a Moto G Power.